# Did I use the gerund "companies advertising snacks..." properly, or should it be "companies' advertising snacks"?

Tags: gerunds, possessives

Companies advertising snacks in an attractive manner entices children into buying them.

Comment: Why do you think it is a gerund? A gerund is a noun. You can't say "in an attractive manner" about a noun.

Comment: @Astralbee "Smiling in an attractive manner will help you to make friends."

Answer (score 0):

No, you didn't use a gerund properly. You shouldn't use a gerund.

It's true that "advertising" can be a gerund. But when a verb becomes a noun, you can no longer use adverbs with it. For example, you could say "the company is *advertising badly*", but you would have to say "the company has *bad advertising*".

You go on to refer to the *manner* in which the advertising is done. You *do* something in a certain manner, so you are clearly referring to a *verb*.

And because 'advertising' is not a gerund, you should not use a possessive noun, either.

Comment: Thanks. What about in this sentence: "Companies advertising junk food is wrong". Is "companies advertising junk food" a gerund?

Comment: @onoseshaibu the sentence you just wrote is not wrong. There's just no gerund. 'Companies' is a noun, and 'advertising' is a verb'.